# Предупреждение при выдвижении недавно разбаненных

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, выборы

При каждом редактировании речи номинанта на модератора выводится следующее сообщение:

[image]

Проблемы:

1. Сообщение выводится всегда, а не только при создании поста.
2. Сообщение не локализовано.
3. Затенён весь экран, а не только область за сообщением.
4. Активные элементы в сообщении (кнопки и ссылка) невозможно нажать.
5. Сообщение сползло направо.
6. Согласно последним новостям, **сообщение ложно**.

Текст:

> **You've been suspended from one or more Stack Exchange sites during the past year.**
>
> Recent suspensions tend to be a distraction during elections, distracting voters from the your qualifications and depriving other candidates of much-needed scrutiny during this critical period. **You should avoid nominating in any election until at least 1 year has passed from the end of your last suspension.**
>
> If you feel there are extenuating circumstances that should permit you to run in this election, please [contact the Stack Exchange team](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) and let us know. If you do not do this, your nomination may be removed without further warning.
>
> <kbd>OK - I won't run for election this time</kbd> <kbd>I want to continue</kbd>

---

Bugs:

1. The message is displayed on every edit of the text, not only during creation.
2. The message is not localized.
3. The whole screen is dimmed, not just the area behind the message box.
4. Controls (the buttons and the link) in the message box are unclickable.
5. The message is stuck to the right side of the screen.
6. According to the latest news, the message is a lie.

Comment: Я глядя на картинку сначала подумал, что это по следам [чата](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=40487445#40487445). Пока текст не прочитал.

Comment: [Пораженец](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85), но как-то условно (забавно у них там)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a relatively new feature which for some reason wasn't localized when created.

I've added the strings to localization, so these should be available to translate soon (after the next build - after rev 2017.10.13.27422).

Thanks for reporting!

---

I have also fixed bugs 1, 3, 4 and 5 - the last 3 were all CSS related, and with the first I added a missing check.

As for your "bug" 6, I have no idea what you mean. If you were suspended anywhere on the network in the last year, this message is supposed to come up. I don't know what you mean by it being a lie.

Comment: There're UI issues in addition to lack of l10n. Do you want me to translate me the whole bug report into English?

Comment: Eh. I missed the other issues :/

Comment: Added English translation.

Comment: As to issue #6, Ru.SO's CM said that there're no "extenuating circumstances" and no exceptions. It's more of a local political issue rather than a global "bug" per se, also irrelevant as of now as I've withdrawn my application due to personal disagreements with administration going way beyond bans.